# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe') in Unit Test NgOnInIt

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-test

I tried a lot of SO Question's answers but nothing worked for this.so in mt test im doing something like this.

```
const stubStudentService = jasmine.createSpyObj('StudentsCrudService',['getAllStudents','updateStudent']);
const stubWebSocketService = jasmine.createSpyObj('WebsocketService',['getNotified']);

describe('StudentsListComponent', () => {
  let component: StudentsListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StudentsListComponent>;;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [StudentsListComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        { provide: StudentsCrudService, useValue: stubStudentService },
        { provide: WebsocketService, useValue: stubWebSocketService },
        NotificationService,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StudentsListComponent);
    stubStudentService.getAllStudents.and.returnValue(of(studentPayload));
    stubWebSocketService.getNotified.and.returnValue(of('success'));
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

 it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

In my component, it look like this

```
  constructor(
    private studentService: StudentsCrudService,
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    private webSocketNotifier: WebsocketService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.studentSubscription();
    this.webSocketSubscription();
  }

  studentSubscription() {
    this.studentQueryRef =  this.studentService
    .getAllStudents()
    this.initSubscription.add(
      this.studentQueryRef
        .valueChanges.subscribe((response) => {
          this.paginatedStudents = {...response.data.paginateStudents}
        })
    );
  }
```

When I run the test im getting `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'subscribe') at StudentsListComponent.studentSubscription`. I tried so many things but nothing worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first `fixture.detectChanges` is when `ngOnInit` is called.

You have mocked `studentService` correctly but you haven't mocked the return of `getAllStudents` incorrectly.

Try this (follow comments with !!):

```
const stubStudentService = jasmine.createSpyObj('StudentsCrudService',['getAllStudents','updateStudent']);
const stubWebSocketService = jasmine.createSpyObj('WebsocketService',['getNotified']);

describe('StudentsListComponent', () => {
  let component: StudentsListComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<StudentsListComponent>;
  // !! make the following changes
  let stubStudentService: jasmine.SpyObj<StudentCrudService>;
  let stubWebSocketService: jasmine.SpyObj<WebsocketService>;
  
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // !! assign the spies in a beforeEach so they are fresh for every test
    stubStudentService = jasmine.createSpyObj('StudentsCrudService', 
      ['getAllStudents','updateStudent']);
    stubWebSocketService = jasmine.createSpyObj('WebsocketService', 
    ['getNotified']);

    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [StudentsListComponent],
      imports: [],
      providers: [
        { provide: StudentsCrudService, useValue: stubStudentService },
        { provide: WebsocketService, useValue: stubWebSocketService },
        NotificationService,
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  });

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StudentsListComponent);
    // !! change below to return object of valueChanges
    stubStudentService.getAllStudents.and.returnValue({ valueChanges: of(studentPayload) });
    stubWebSocketService.getNotified.and.returnValue(of('success'));
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    // !! the below fixture.detectChanges will call ngOnInit
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

 it('should create', () => {
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
 });
```

The above should hopefully fix your problem.

Comment: getting error in `valuechanges:of(studentPayload)`.it says `The expected type comes from property 'valueChanges' which is declared here on type 'QueryRef<{ paginateStudents: PaginatedData; }, EmptyObject>`

Comment: Okay, try this. `stubStudentService.getAllStudents.and.returnValue({ valueChanges: of(studentPayload) } as any);`. Add the `as any` to satisfy TypeScript.

Comment: Even if I used any type. on run time it will throw Type error saying `QueryRef<{paginateStudent: PaginatedStudent}>`.needed . I can't figure out how to mock query Ref type because it's provided by angular apollo library.

Comment: Sorry, not sure then.